# How to get remote Git repository in VSTS using SSH?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've got private repo which uses Cert auth for https connection. This is why I can't use standard getting

[image]

But I can clone repo using SSH. Is there any way to do it in VSTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not supported in VSTS, you can follow up this uservoice: [fetch source from Git via SSH in Visual Studio Team Services](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18572485-fetch-source-from-git-via-ssh-in-visual-studio-tea).

You may get the source by calling `git clone ssh://xxx` command through command line task during the build.

Comment: Thank you for advice! `git clone ssh://xxx` works for me